Water filtration loop and pipe diameter
I’m adding a water filtration loop to a residential home. The copper pipe coming from the street into the house is 1” in diameter. I’m going to split this main line so I can run it to the sediment filter/water softener and back. It’s probably about 30’ round trip. If I build this filtration loop with 3/4” pipe, and then connect it back to the 1” pipe, how significantly will this effect the water pressure as it transitions 3/4” back to 1”? I mean, I know it will reduce water pressure a little, but will it be a noticeable decline in quality?

You'll probably lose some flow rate and pressure simply running it through the filtration system.

It depends entirely on flow rate. At zero flow, there is no pressure drop.
You actually haven't given enough info for a complete answer, so I'll give you an example. If you use schedule 40 pipe and the flow rate is 1 GPM, both pipe sizes give negligible pressure drop.
For the same grade of pipe in one straight run of 30 feet at 15 GPM, 1" pipe gives a pressure drop of 1.9 PSI and 3/4" pipe gives a pressure drop of 6.5 PSI.
Find an online plumbing pressure drop calculator, enter your specific parameters for pipe grade, size, flow rate and number of elbows and you can answer your own question.
